# String conversion for elements in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I have one `NSArray` that has names of documents to be presented in a `UITableView`.  The `NSString`s in the `NSArray` have spaces so an entry would look like, "John Smith".  Then I have pdfs that correspond to each of the table entries.  These pdf entries are not the same name.  They would be something like, "JohnSmith.pdf".  I created a method to basically convert the names to the pdfs in order to present the appropriate pdfs.  In my method, I basically hard coded the values

```
NSUInteger loopCount = 0;
for ( ; loopCount < [array count]; loopCount++) {
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:loopCount] isEqualToString:@"John Smith"]) {
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCount withObject:@"JohnSmith.pdf"];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  That's all I could think of since the data was already made to have different names.  Thx.

Comment: Are the file names in a consistent format based on the first/last name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe you can use something like this:

```
NSString *filename = [[name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSUInteger loopCount = 0;
 for ( ; loopCount < [array count]; loopCount++) {
    NSString* name = [array objectAtIndex:loopCount];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCount withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@.pdf", [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]]];
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to declare and initialize `loopCount` there.

Comment: thanks, I have edited it. anyway, it was meant to be a code fragment based on the code in the question...

Comment: Oops, I guess I missed that. Sorry.